# Ribosomal RNA amount in a Drosophila cell

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, mrna, ribosome

I am isolation RNA from Drosophila larvae brain with [TRIzol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trizol) method. What percentage of extracted RNA will be ribosomal RNA? I am only interested in mRNA, so I am trying to figure out whether I need to get rid of rRNA. Thanks

Comment: Percentage of _what_? Total cell mass/volume? Of total RNA moieties? Of total nucleic acids?

Comment: Ratio of ribosomal RNA in total RNA if I rephrase it.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question to something like "I am extracting RNA using methodX, what percentage of extracted RNA will be ribosomal?" The percentages will also depend on the method used to extract the RNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The protocol you are using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanidinium_thiocyanate-phenol-chloroform_extraction) will not only leave the sample with rRNA but also non coding RNA.

Many RNA protocols will separate [mRNA by affinity of a carrier to the polyA tail](http://www.fgsc.net/neurosporaprotocols/HowtoisolatemRNA%20final.pdf).  This protocol references an older paper that estimates that [only 5% of RNA is mRNA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/158528).  I'd be surprised if this ratio changed by more than 2-3 fold in drosophila.

I assume that %age is by weight but it could be a densitometry measurement which is similarly interpreted.

Comment: Thanks! As a subsequent question: Do you think that huge amount of rRNA will affect my downstream experiments such as RT-qPCR? I am only interested in mRNAs.

Comment: I've not done qPCR.  I would not hesitate to compare multiple standard protocols to get a better sample. Looking at a couple of qPCR protocols you're right I only see Triazol preparations used.  PCR is pretty efficient as long as the primers are specific.  Some more homework before doing the experiment won't hurt you :)